# Count and show unique values in a column given another column in R

Tags: r

I want to know what are the unique values in a column given a value from another column, for exmple, I have the following data frame:

| name | category |
| --- | --- |
| A | Pr |
| A | Pr |
| B | Pr |
| A | N |
| B | N |

The result should be like this:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pr | 2 | 1 |
| N | 1 | 1 |

Comment: In base you could try `tapply(data$Name, data$category, table)`

Comment: `df %>% dplyr::count(name, category) %>% tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = n)`